# How to merge associative array with indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

i'm sorry before if my english so bad,
how to merge second array (indexed array) with first array (associative array) to be associative array

first array like this :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'level_name' => 'HTML 1'
  1 => 
    array
      'level_name' => 'HTML 2'
  2 => 
    array
      'level_name' => 'HTML 3'
```

second array like this :

```
array
  0 => int 23
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 34
```

if i expected to be array like this, how to solve it

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'level_name' => 'HTML 1'
      'counter' => '23'
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'level_name' => 'HTML 2'
      'counter' => '1'
  2 => 
    array
      'level_name' => 'HTML 3' 
      'counter' => '34'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use foreach

```
$levels = array('0'=>[ 'level_name' => 'HTML 1'],'1'=>['level_name' => 'HTML 2'],'2'=>['level_name' => 'HTML 3']);
$counter=array(
 '0'=> '23',
  '1'=> '1',
  '2'=>'34');
$arr=[];
foreach ($levels as $key => $level) {
    $arr []=['level_name'=>$level['level_name'],'counter'=>$counter[$key]];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to iterate the elements in the first array, adding the `counter` element to each array:

```
array_walk($array1, function (&$v, $k) use ($array2) {
    $v = array_merge($v, array('counter' => $array2[$k]));
});
print_r($array1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [level_name] => HTML 1
            [counter] => 23
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [level_name] => HTML 2
            [counter] => 1
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [level_name] => HTML 3
            [counter] => 34
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PqDmH)